# ¿Crear regla para campo numerico vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Estoy tratando de crear un input numérico, que sea validado por una regla que no permita ingresar nulos y solo valores mayores a 0 , he intentado lo siguiente sin resultados, llevo solo días aprendiendo vue gracias.

```
<v-text-field type="number" :rules="numberRule"></v-text-field>

numberRule: (v) => {
   v => !!v || 'campo requerido',
   v => Number(v) > 0 || 'valor tiene que ser mayor a 0',
},
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que la segunda regla es el problema, podría ser `Number(v) > 0`

Comment: si la segunda regla da errores, me lanza la misma alerta para todos los números sin validar los ceros , el problema es que desconozco la sintaxis para validar en estos casos

Comment: ¿La primera si funciona? ¿Ha quedado la segunda con el código que te di?

Comment: la primera validación funciona , cuando valido que el numero sea mayor a cero falla , lo intente de varias formas con Number(v) > 0 sin resultados, si me puedes indicar como iria exactamente la sintaxis por favor

Comment: Ya veo, no me había fijado en toda la expresión, sino solo en las reglas individuales, te dejé una  respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Escribe la regla de esta manera:

```
<v-text-field :rules="numberRule" type="number" required></v-text-field>

 numberRule: [
    v => v.length > 0 || 'campo requerido',
    v => v > 0 || 'El valor debe ser mayor a cero'
  ]
```

Edición: Recién probé en una aplicación y esta combinación de reglas fue la que me funcionó.

Comment: me arroja la validación para todos los números , no valida que el valor sea distinto de 0, por algún motivo no funciona de esta forma , gracias por la ayuda de todas formas estimado.

Comment: No entiendo bien, es decir, te deja meter negativos? ceros? otra cosa que no sea un número? null?

Comment: me refiero que me arroja la validación "'valor tiene que ser mayor a 0" para todos los numeros me explico ingreso ejemplo 110400 y me arroja la validacion , independiente del numero de coloque

Comment: agregue una imagen para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Listo, hasta ahora había escrito todo en el navegador, recién probé en una aplicación y las reglas que dejé ahora me funcionan. Un saludo.

Comment: no logro hacerlo funcionar como mencionas :c , no se que esta mal , no deberia ser tan complicado validar algo como esto , sigo con el mismo problema , gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: ¿Copiaste todo el texto de las reglas? Mirá aquí, está funcionando justo ese conjunto de reglas https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-forked-w66f5

Comment: Ahora que veo la cadena, el problema puede ser que estás insertando un serparador de miles, eso no suele escribirse al colocar un número, quizás al presentarlo, pero no al ingresarlo en un campo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124898/discussion-between-jachguate-and-javier-antonio-aguayo-aguilar).